# PHP Using str_replace() to convert date format

Tags: php, date

Ive been stuck on this, relatively simple problem for too long now.

1. I scrape a site and get date in this format ***Fri, Dec 1, 2017***
2. I then use `substr($date, 5);` to remove the day name. which returns the following:  ***Dec 1, 2017***
3. I then use `str_replace($new_date, ',',' ')`; where I want to remove the comma `,` and replace it with white space. So that I have a date format of ***Dec 1 2017***

Ultimately what Im trying to do is convert the date Dec 1 2017 to the format date('Y-m-d) but before I can do that I first need to figure out what exactly is wrong with code below.

### Code

```
 $date = $cells2->item(0)->textContent;
        $new_date = substr($date, 5);
        $new_date = str_replace($new_date, ',',' ');
        echo $new_date;
```

### Problem

My error is in step 3 `str_replace()` the problem is it is real hard to figure out what exactly is wrong since when I `echo $new_date` nothing gets displayed on the screen.

Would greatly appreciate it if someone more experienced can give my code a scan, and provide some advice.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using str_replace() when PHP has built in functions just for this purpose?

Comment: `$new_date = str_replace(',', ' ', $new_date);` is the correct syntax. `str_replace(search, replace, subject)`

Comment: @JohnConde do you perhaps have the name of the function?

Comment: @Erwin wrong syntax. Ouch Thanks. If you add it as answer I'll accept.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Just clearing up. But i also recommend doing what @JohnConde suggests. Or check the duplicate link  :)

Comment: @Erwin just to clarify what @JohnCode is suggesting is that I can directly convert to `Fri, Dec 1, 2017` to the format `2017-12-01` using a build in function...?

Comment: @Erwin im seeing the duplicate link. Many thanks guys

Comment: echo date('M j Y', strtotime($date)); should be the correct way to do this. The date() function reference has it all : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php